# How stable is Babel's "stage-0" preset?

Tags: babeljs

I wonder how stable Babel's Stage 0 features really are. Babel only ever implements select [Stage 0 features](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/).

Some developers say it's "dangerous" to use Stage 0 features. But I want to look at the question in this way: Have any features in Babel's "stage-0" preset historically been discarded?

Comment: I'm thinking that Babel only implements features that have a high likelihood of advancing through additional stages, and that once Babel goes to the trouble of offering a feature, adoption among developers will help push it along too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel doesn't control the stages. They are from TC39, the standards group that manages the language specification. You can see more information [on their Github repo for proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

It's important to understand up front that "stage 0" essentially means that a member of the committee came to a meeting and said "I want to explore this thing I thought of that could be cool". There is absolutely no guarantee that something at this point will become stabilized.

> Babel only ever implements select Stage 0 features.

That's definitely the case, because often times proposals will change a bunch as they migrate through the state process. If a proposal is one that extra likely to change, we (I'm one of Babel's maintainers) are much less likely to want to accept an implementation of it, since it is harder to maintain over time and will likely cause users pain.

> Have any features in Babel's "stage-0" preset historically been discarded?

The main ones that come to mind:

- [`RegExp.escape`](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape)
- [`Map/Set.prototype.toJSON`](https://github.com/DavidBruant/Map-Set.prototype.toJSON)
- [Callable `class` constructors](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/workingdocs/callconstructor.md)
- [Array comprehension syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions)
- The ability to do `export default from "";` instead of `export { default } from "";`

> Some developers say it's "dangerous" to use Stage 0 features.

I think it's important to qualify what people mean by "dangerous" here. Danger probably doesn't mean that your code will outright break randomly, but it could mean that you end up using a feature that then changes. Decorators for instance are an example where the community aggressively adopted the spec as it was implemented in Babel originally, and the spec has now changed massively from that implementation. You can probably write a decorator to programmatically detect the two cases, but no decorator written to work with the old behavior will work with the new behavior without being updated. Babel hasn't landed an implementation of the current spec yet.

Another big piece of "dangerous" to me is that, if you use non-standard functionality, it is harder for developers to come up to speed on your codebase, especially juniors. If you're developing a large production application, that could be a big barrier for people. It also means that searching for answers about a given syntax can be harder, or even worse it could be wrong because the spec has changed over time.

I'm personally of the opinion that we should delete the stage 0-2 presets in favor of users explicitly choosing experimental proposals to activate. I personally have no problem with people using low-stage proposals, but you should absolutely be deciding specifically what to use, rather than blanket-enabling `stage-0`.

Also keep in mind that while these points are important, they also probably apply less to some small hobby project. If it's your project and you have the time to maintain it, by all means do whatever you want. Where the danger comes in most for me is that codebases mostly grow, and the more experimental features you use, the most unstable things can be over time, which can harm maintainability.